# How can I expose local data_path to the temporary_job_container (awx-job-xxxxx)?

Tags: ansible, local, nfs, ansible-awx

My playbook running from awx need to check the file of nfs. Therefore I want to expose mount_path of local host to the temporary container, or mount pvc of nfs_volume to the temporary container. I tried to mount pvc of nfs_volume to the awx-ee container, but my playbook failed because the job isn't running on the awx-ee container.
Any method is fine, so please let me know how to refer to file of nfs from a running job . Thank you in advance.

- minikube
- awx: 19.1.0
- awx-operator: 0.9.0

```
apiVersion: awx.ansible.com/v1beta1
kind: AWX
metadata:
  name: awx
spec:
  tower_ee_images:
    - name: my-custom-awx-ee
      image: xxxxxxx/my-custom-awx-ee
  tower_ingress_type: NodePort
  tower_projects_persistence: true
  tower_projects_existing_claim: awx-projects-claim02
  tower_ee_extra_volume_mounts: |
    - name: myawx-nfs
      mountPath: /nfs

  tower_extra_volumes: |
    - name: myawx-nfs
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: myawx-nfs-pvc
```

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same thing.  After hours of fruitlessly searching the web we found this:

Within the AWX GUI, go to "Instance Groups" and from there either create or edit a Container Group.

In the details of the container group, you'll see a section called "Pod Spec override".

You can put something like this in there:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  namespace: <your-awx-k8s-namespace>
spec:
  containers:
    - image: <your awx-ee image>
      name: worker
      args:
        - ansible-runner
        - worker
        - '--private-data-dir=/runner'
      volumeMounts:
      - name: <your-nfs-mount-name>
        mountPath: <local path to mount on>
  volumes:
  - name: <your volume name>
    nfs:
      server: <your nfs server name>
      path: <remote location of share on server>
```

This will mount the nfs folder directly on the temporary worker pods and then you don't have to try and expose any paths to them :)  Hope it helps!

Comment: Are you sure it is `volumeMount` and not `volumeMounts` ?

Comment: Yes you are correct, I missed an 's' when I was typing it in here.